# How do I add an image in Playgrounds for iPad?

Tags: swift, sprite, playgrounds

I’m writing a simple 2D game using SpriteKit with Playgrounds for iPad. I’m trying to add a menu button using the following code:

```
SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: )
```

How do I point to an image? I’ve tried adding an image to the project using the little plus in the top right-hand corner, but when I do that I get the error “cannot convert value of type ‘UIImage’ to expected argument type ‘String’”. So, how do I point to an image?

Answer (score 1):

You should drag your image to the `Resources` directory.

[image]

Then you should use name of the file which is `String`. That's why you got this error.

```swift
let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
// or
let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image.png")
```

When you initialize UIImage like that you will see the preview of the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the Assets.xcassets file and click on the `+` in the lower left of the main window to add an image.  Select `New Image Set`, name your image and drag files into the image slots.

Then this code will work.

```
let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image.png")
```

But this will also work.

```
let node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image")
```

Good luck.